# node.js + mysql + ejs update screen information without reloading page after data insert

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, ajax, ejs

i'm trying to update my list of tasks after inserting, currently when i press the button, in my ejs page i submit a post request, than in my controller i have app.post("/mypage") and here i use connection.query() to do my insert, then i use the res.redirect() to reload the page, so my app.get("/myPage") reloads all my data and show it on my page, is there a way to this without reloading it? i was thinking of using jQuery Ajax, but cannot find enough any source of information regarding this.

ejs modal to add

```
<div class="modal" id="addTask">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="/studentDashTaskAdd/<%=uID%>/<%=pID%>" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input
                id="task_title"
                name="taskTitle"
                type="text"
                class="validate"
              />
              <label for="task_title">Title</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <textarea
                id="textarea1"
                name="taskDescription"
                class="materialize-textarea"
              ></textarea>
              <label for="textarea1">Description</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="taskDeadine"
                name="taskDeadline"
                class="datepicker"
              />
              <label for="taskDeadine">Deadline</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <select id="priority" name="taskPriority">
                <option value="1">Low</option>
                <option value="2">medium</option>
                <option value="3">High</option>
              </select>
              <label for="priority">Priority</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="submidTask" class="btn blue right">
            Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
```

```
//adding task from student dash
  app.post(
    "/studentDashTaskAdd/:userID/:projectID",
    parsed,
    (req, res, next) => {
      //console.log(req.body);
      connection.query(
        "INSERT INTO task(priority,description,deadline,title,userID,projectID) values('" +
          req.body.taskPriority +
          "','" +
          req.body.taskDescription +
          "','" +
          req.body.taskDeadline +
          "','" +
          req.body.taskTitle +
          "','" +
          req.params.userID +
          "','" +
          req.params.projectID +
          "');"
      );
      //console.log(req.params.userID);

      res.redirect(
        "/studentDash/" + req.params.userID + "/" + req.params.projectID
      );
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've started using your combo of tools recently so i'm not sure i'm giving you the optimal way to do it but i would go this way with jquery :

JQuery

```
$.post(
    "studentDashTaskAdd",
    {yourValues},
    (data, status) => 
    {

            switch(status){
                case "error":
            // Manage your issues here
                    return;
                case "timeout":
            // Manage your issues here
                    return;
                case "parsererror":
            // Manage your issues here
                    return;
            }
        // then either you send back the full list and treat it here or just append what you just sent to your server
    },
    "json"
    })
```

NodeJS

```
app.post(
    "/studentDashTaskAdd",(req,res) = >{
        const query = " your query"; //req.body still works in this case for your params
        connection.query(query,(err,results) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(400).send({message:err});
            }
            res.send("your data as json or anything to tell your ajax Ok It's done");
        })
});
```

I would be glad if anyone corrects me if i'm wrong i'm still learing :P

P.S. : You can also just add an id to your button like id="addTask" and then use `$("#addTask").click( () => {//what i've done above})`

Comment: "P.S. : You can also just add an id to your button like id="addTask" and then use $("#addTask").click( () => {//what i've done above})" this is what i'm kinda doing, but where do write your jquery? i'm currently doing it in the ejs file, because if i try to put my code in the static file it doesn't recognise the data and throws errors

Comment: I would guess you are trying to use data you have sent to your EJS page but didn't print anywhere and you print it in your script tag ? A work around would be to have hidden html tags with data or values in it. `<div id="test" data-nameOfYourValue="data" hidden></div>` and in jquery you can access it like this `$("#test").attr("data-nameOfYourValue")`